# Removing string property on time with/without moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am creating a countdown on a session that is 20 minutes.   When I do a get request I get back

```
20.
```

This is fine.  My next step is to set this so that it can be subtracted by

```
1000 milliseconds on an $interval
```

I have tried the following code

```
  var d = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');
  moment(d.asMinutes(),'mm').format('mm:ss');
```

Which returns

```
"21:00"
```

This is great, but the problem is now I have a string.  I am not sure how I can start subtracting seconds off of this timer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a session timeout there's no need to complicate things, use `setTimeout`:

```
const SESSION_MAX = 20 * 60 * 1000; // 20 min to milliseconds
setTimeout(logOutFunction, SESSION_MAX);
```

If for some reason you want more control, then just work with the integers returned by a Date object's native `getTime`:

```
let start = Date.now();
let end = start + (20 * 60 * 1000);
const INTERVAL = 1000; //ms
```

Then increment `start` on a clocktick and check if its `>=` end.

Comment: okay.  I actually am going this route now.  So basically when i am looking to hit end 20 minutes from the current time.  thanks!